# How to render text streak animation?

Tags: text-object

I'm a beginner to Blender and 3D authoring in general. I would like to mimic a text intro animation sequence as depicted in the first 5 seconds of this video: https://youtu.be/kzyFBlNRohs.

I have tried rendering 2D text with a glossy material. I added and animated streaks using a glare node as described in this video tutorial: https://youtu.be/-LuPck9FJ4Y. I changed the angle offset from 0 to 180, but the streak rotation is not what I would like.

I think what I need to do is, for each character:
1. Create a plane on top of the character
2. Somehow render streaks to this plane
3. Rotate the plane

Can you provide any help/assistance to a noob? Thanks.

Comment: Drop us your Blend file.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J9sOi5z_2KoTsLlejIsoKmQPWEI1pp75